# I get error when I use the apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I created a normal project in android studio and considering to the tutorials I wanted to create an `aar` file from that project but I get the following error:

```
Gradle: 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\tec\AndroidStudioProjects\B\B\build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':B'.
> Plugin with id 'com.android.library' not found.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
 Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip'.
```

My `gradle` file is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your script:

First of all use the latest gradle plugin.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
```

Then update your gradle wrapper.
Open up this file in your project:

```
<Project>/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip
```

Finally remove the line `apply plugin: 'android'`